# Simple Esri/ArcGIS Online connection using a link or iframe

Tags: gis, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

I was asked by a potential client if I can have my software interact with Esri/ArcGIS Online.

Use case: users is logged into SomeRandomSoftwareApp and is looking at a Widget, this Widget  includes an Esri asset id, the user clicks a link that passes that ID to Esri/ArcGIS Online and behind the scenes the user is logged into Esri and they see the data associated with the Esri/ArcGIS Online.

Thanks, Keith

Comment: With Esri you mean ArcGIS Online?, is the user data in Esri secure?

Comment: Yes, ArcGIS Online, thanks for the clarification, I am new to this product. Yes it is secure meaning there would have to be authentication behind it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have two options for this: API Keys or Application Credentials.

The first one, is a permanent token generated by the owner of the data that will allow the application easy access to it. This is still in beta, and it was not ready for use the last time I check some time ago.

The second one, the owner of the data will generate credentials for your application. With this credentials you will have to request a token each time you want to access the data, all this via OAuth 2.0.

Check the docs for more details [ArcGIS Services - Security](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/mapping-apis-and-services/security/)

Comment: This is a great answer, once I get a "token" via OAuth would I be able to do something like... (the link obviously is just mocked up but want to verify the passing of an ASSET id or some sort of unique ID would work) 

<a href="https://ArcGIS.com/myclientsportal/ASSET-ID">Click here to view Asset</a>

Or an iframe
<iframe src="https://ArcGIS.com/myclientsportal/ASSET-ID"></iframe>

Comment: I am not sure what is the information the client want to see, but you should be able to access any secure service. Now in relation to the iframe, and guessing you would like to use it for a map application, I am not sure if this mechanism will work. But, you have other way to create maps yourself, like using ArcGIS JS API, depending on how much functionality is need it could be something simple. And if you need help you can ask here :)